# Digit Counter MatLab

Tags: matlab, function, counter

I am creating a function that counts the number of digits in an integer. The answer keeps coming out as zero however. It's late and I am probably overlooking something very simple. Thanks.

```
function [ count ] = CountDigits( input )

s = int2str(input);      % convert the input to a string
count = 0;               % initialize count to zero
n = length(s);           % total length of s

    for k = 1 : 1 : n
        if s(1,k) >= '0' && s(1,k) <= '9'           % is digit
            count = count + 1;                      % add to count if digit
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: isn't it simpler to just use `count=floor(abs(log10(input))+1)`?

Comment: @natan: my thoughts (almost) exactly, but I think you ought to take the absolute value before taking the logarithm lest things become complex.

Comment: yep, I was a bit careless there, thanks for noticing... (and my +1)

Answer (score 4):

I think you're overlooking something straightforward like

```
floor(log10(abs(your_integer_here))+1)
```

Answer (score 3):

`numel(num2str(abs(your_integer_here)))` 
does the trick.

Comment: `abs()` is necessary if negative integer

Comment: I don't like this answer much more than OP's.  This counts the number of characters in the string representation of the integer, it's an unnecessary conceptual step from counting the number of digits in an integer.